# adonisjs github collaboration not possible?

Tags: github, adonis.js

I’m working with a friend to make a web application using adonisjs. I have the front page done and it is looking pretty slick at localhost:3333.
I need my partner who joined the repository to be able to work on it as well. He cloned my repo after installing the necessities. When he tries to adonis serve --dev, it says he isn’t in an adonisjs app. He can’t use the new command because it says the folder has to be empty (and he already has the framework files from the cloning, right?). So, he can’t launch the server because his computer doesn’t recognize it as an adonisjs app. What should we do so it acknowledges his clone is one?

Comment: Are you both on the same branch, and is he running the command from the correct directory?

Answer (score 0):

when installing adonis your partner needs to install adonis globally `npm i -g @adonisjs/cli`

Then, when you have adoniscli installed make sure you install such dependencies `npm install`

Now, you can go to the adonis folder and run the project `adonis serve --dev`